# Merge Featureclasses if there is more than one in the FeatureClassSet

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, merge

i want to check through all my gdb if a FeatureClassSet contains more than one FeatureClass. If so merge them and save the result in an other gdb otherwise just copy them to the gdb. It sounds really simple to me - but it is not working. So far I've got this:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

workspace = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
EK = arcpy.GetParameter(1)

outWorkspace = r"C:\...\20_Ges.gdb"
Zieldataset = os.path.join(outWorkspace, EK)

fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=EK)
for item in fc: 
    item.count(<1):
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion (workspace, Zieldataset)
    else:
        arcpy.Merge_management(fc, Zieldataset)
```

I connected the script to a model that iterates the variable EK and sets the workspace. The error in the script is in the line that starts with "item.count".
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the help from @smiller I found all mistakes:

- use len() insead of count
- then the workspace and index were missing
- finally it had a problem with the "else" part if not >1 so i replaced it with a elsif >2 and it worked.

Here the working script:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

ws = r"C:\......21_IN.gdb"
EK = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
outWorkspace = r"C:\....21_Ges.gdb"
temp=EK+"_temp"
Zieldataset = os.path.join(outWorkspace, EK)
Zieldataset_temp = os.path.join(outWorkspace, temp)

env.workspace = ws 
fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=EK)

if len(fc) > 1:
    arcpy.Merge_management(fc, Zieldataset_temp)
    arcpy.Dissolve_management (Zieldataset_temp, Zieldataset, dissolve_field="", statistics_fields="", multi_part="MULTI_PART", unsplit_lines="DISSOLVE_LINES")
    arcpy.Delete_management (Zieldataset_temp)
elif len(fc) < 2:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc[0], outWorkspace, EK)
```

Answer (score 2):

I adjusted your code on line 12 (originally starting with item.count) to use Python syntax for if statements - added the keyword `if` and removed the test `<1` from parenthesis.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

ws = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
EK = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

outWorkspace = r"C:\...\20_Ges.gdb"
Zieldataset = os.path.join(outWorkspace, EK)

arcpy.env.workspace = ws
fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=EK)
for item in fc: 
    if item.count == 1:   # This will never be true, see below
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion (ws, Zieldataset)
    else:
        arcpy.Merge_management(fc, Zieldataset)
```

However, I don't think will do exactly what you are looking for, as the ListFeatureClasses output is a list of individual feature classes, and you are testing a count method with no parameters for each individual feature class. item.count is a built-in method to a unicode object. Since `item` is a string, the [`count` method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/count) counts the number of occurrences of a substring. For example, if a lot of your feature classes had the name `myfcnameis4512345` and you perform `item.count('fcname')`, the result would be `1`. If you perform `item.count('45')` the result would be `2` because it found 2 occurrences of the substring `45`.

Instead, just check the length of the list of feature classes, such as below:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

ws = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
EK = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

outWorkspace = r"C:\...\20_Ges.gdb"
Zieldataset = os.path.join(outWorkspace, EK)
env.workspace = ws
fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=EK)
if len(fc) > 1: 
    arcpy.Merge_management(fc, Zieldataset)
elif len(fc) == 1:        
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(os.path.join(ws, fc[0]), Zieldataset, fc[0])
else:
    print "Empty feature dataset {}, nothing to convert".format(Zieldataset)
```

EDIT: I explicitly included a call to either `arcpy.env.workspace` or `env.workspace` depending on how the imports were called. This is because `ListFeatureClasses` requires a workspace to be set. To avoid confusion I renamed your variable `workspace` to `ws`.

EDIT: I think the GetParameter, which returns an object, might cause some unexpected results. I've changed to using GetParameterAsText, which returns a string.

Comment: oh. You're right. Thanks. But it is still not working. maybe because the featureclass to featureclass does not know what the feature in the selected feature set is named...just a guess. Is there an additional field step needed?

Comment: Ah, yeah - good catch. You've already imported `os`, so I think you can just use `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(os.path.join(workspace, fc[0]), Zieldataset, fc[0])` This assumes you want the fc named the same in the new gdb. (Third parameter can be changed to give a different fc name.)

Comment: okay thanks again for your help. I tried it out. But the IndexError: list index out of range - appeared and what does the [0] mean?

Comment: and i'm not sure if I can combine a list with a path? I tried os.path.join(workspace, fc) before as separate parameter - but it wouldn't work.

Comment: OK, interesting. It looks like we may need to check for having an empty feature_dataset. The brackets are an index, and Python indexes start with zero. The presumption was that you would have a list called `fc` with lengh 1, or a list of `fc` with length more than 1. The List Index out of range message tells me that ListFeatureClasses came up empty.

Comment: With the index, you are not combining the path with a list, you are combining the path with the first element of the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86338/discussion-between-smiller-and-lisa).

Comment: Ah you're right..I remember the indexing - then it is not searching at the right place...because there are no empty feature data sets